# Summing rows based on conditional in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand how to sum up a subset of rows based on 2 indices in Pandas.  The first index groups the rows and the second index will determine which rows to sum.  For a minimal example suppose I have the dataframe

```
index1 | index2 | value
------------------------
  a    |    1   |  10
  a    |    2   |  11
  a    |    3   |  12
  b    |    1   |  20
  b    |    2   |  21
  b    |    3   |  22
```

**How can I sum the rows corresponding to index `1` and `2` but still have them grouped under index `a` and `b`.  I.e the following results.**

```
index1 | index2 | value
------------------------
  a    |    1   |  21
  a    |    2   |  12
  b    |    1   |  41
  b    |    2   |  22
```

Here the rows corresponding to `index2` of `1` and `2` have been summed into the new `index2` of `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive a new array/Series from *index2* column as group variable, and then do the summation:

```
df.groupby([df.index1, ~df.index2.isin([1,2]) + 1]).value.sum().reset_index()

#index1 index2  value
#0    a      1     21
#1    a      2     12
#2    b      1     41
#3    b      2     22
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for the minimal example but it doesn't scale. If `index2` has range `1,2,3,4` then this still returns 2 groups in the end (instead of 3).  Do you mind given some explanation to the answer so I can figure out how to tweak it to my needs?

Comment: The above method converts all 1 and 2 to 1, and all other values to 2 as a final group variable so it will have only two groups. You can try replace all 2 with 1 if you just want to combine 1 and 2 as a group while keeping other values as separate, such as `df.groupby([df.index1, df.index2.replace(2, 1)]).value.sum().reset_index()`. The result index will have `2` missing though in this case if you are fine with it.

Comment: this works wonderfully, I'll just adjust the indices afterwards, thanks!